# Converting a package from python2 to python3

Tags: python, django

I've downloaded the Trumbowyg WYSIWYG editor: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/ as well as `django-trumbowyg` for integrating it with django: https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg

However `django-trumbowyg` is written for python2, whereas my app runs on python3. Is it difficult to convert this package to python3? Or is it just a matter of making a few minor changes? How would I go about it?

Comment: Well what happens when you run it under Python 3? Do you get any errors?

Comment: When I did `pip install django-trumbowyg`, it returned this error:

    `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-trumbowyg (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for django-trumbowyg`                        
                        
So I downloaded it and added it to `site-packages`, but the `TrumbowygWidget` didn't work (didn't realise it was only for python2)

Comment: You will want to start with running the tests available in the django-trumbowyg package: https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg/tree/master/tests with Python 3.x.

Comment: How exactly do I run that test?

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html and it will explain how to run your python program as a python 3 file. If you want to have the file written in python 3 you will need to read over how python 3 is different and change those difference.

For your case you would be better off writing your app in python 2 if you aren't dependent on python 3 implementations.

Comment: Just had a read through. Is it possible to do the whole package at once? I tried `2to3 trumbowyg` and got this:
`Can't open trumbowyg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trumbowyg'`

Comment: It will have this error because that file cant be found make sure that it is in the folder